# find matching string in 2 large files contains 400 millions lines in PHP

Tags: php

i am a basic user in php.

i have 2 large files

- file A = 30GB (216 million lines of string)
- file B = 20GB (420 million lines of string)

i want search whatever matching string in file B given by each line in file A
and either print/save the string which are matched

let say

file A contains:

```
{"addr":"werwerwer","err":"asjsjka","id":"ssdf83sdfl"}
{"addr":"acacccaar","err":"xcvxxsd","id":"798asad8sc"}
{"addr":"asdascacx","err":"lkuuiyh","id":"jkllmlkg8a"}
{"addr":"jklsdlkfl","err":"hfjyhts","id":"098dejda1s"}
 ...
```

file B contains:

```
jasdhkjas
werwerwer
iusuahsus
yaiuhasua
opopasjsl
    ...
```

result will print

```
werwerwer
```

and continue search till end of file

i hope to solve this in PHP language
if you think PHP is not efficient/too slow, please provide me a detail coding in other language.

i have searched stackoverflow for the answer but the most i found was mention about 1 million lines, but i thought 400 millions lines is another different way of doing it in terms of time efficiency and coding

prefer PHP-CLI

Comment: sounds for me as if you were working on some kind of plagiarization tool....whatever your purpose is, I would recommend you to use some kind od Database with fulltext search mechanisim or other tools such as elasticsearch, solr, lucene....

Comment: Christian Felix, i just updated my question perhaps your answer will be different :)

Comment: _“but i thought 400 millions lines is another different way of doing it in terms of time efficiency and coding”_ - show us what you got/ found first of all - and _test it._ Only if it doesn’t perform well enough, there’s a need to discuss alternatives here.

Comment: with such a big script - I would probably do it in batches with AJAX. 
This would stop the php from hitting the timeout limit.

Comment: ^^ If you need to do it with php only

Comment: i dont have it, thats why maybe one of you can provide the idea, using "foreach or for" with "array and isset" is my basic option, my thinking was how to chop/slice them in array and working the matching, to save memory, i think avoiding long time consume to work this is not possible, try to save memory and stabilizing the working is more important, because startover is not a good idea

Comment: php-cli is my what i am looking for, using php in web based for this work is more complex

Comment: could do something like this : https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/maximum-filesize-that-can-be-opened-by-fopen/5142/5

Comment: @Stender reading file is not the issue, i think i can overcome that, but putting this large content into array and searching the match was my problem, arraying 400 millions lines without slicing it sounds crazy to me

Comment: with the example I sent you, It loops through the file in segments of your provided block size - meaning that it continues to loop through it, until an end-of-file is met - or until you have met your conditions

Comment: Or - that is how I believe it works. Never had to work with such large files before

Answer (score 0):

this part of my code i managed to overcome reading FileA

```
$block =1024*1024;
if ($fh = fopen("FileA", "r")) { //reading fileA no problem
    $left='';
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    while (!feof($fh)) {
       $temp = fread($fh, $block);  
       $fgetslines = explode("\n",$temp);
       $fgetslines[0]=$left.$fgetslines[0];
       if(!feof($fh) )$left = array_pop($fgetslines);
       foreach ($fgetslines as $k => $line) {
           //ok $line contain the each line of FileA
           //here is what i confused how to read FileB into array and do the matching
           //if it was small file, easy, use read content, explode new line, and become array
           //but this large file, do the same thing, memory issue will occur, even using memory_limit -1
           //so slicing the array of FileB to prevent memory issue, i dont know how to do it
       }
    }
}
```